# How do I stop Banshee from automatically starting when I plug in my Android device?

Tags: 11.04, banshee, android

I set Banshee up as the default app to launch when I plug in my Android device, but have changed my mind.  I'd prefer that Ubuntu simply mount it as a drive and leave the rest to me.

How would I go about changing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing the default behaviour for plugged in devices in Nautilus settings (the tab is called Devices I believe).

Like "Insert Audio CD" --> "open player" etc

Comment: I found the preference under **/apps/nautilus/preferences** with key name **media_autorun_x_content_start_app**.  I was that what you were referring to?  Editing it to remove the audio player from the list seemed to do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: kind of - I actually meant in Nautilus/Settings Menu. But it's the same